# Expand a single row into multiple rows based on filters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for an example or maybe a little hint to show filters based on number of filters available

Let's assume that I have a list :

```
<dl class="filter-list clearfix filter-list-row-2">
    <dt>Type:</dt>
    <dd class="active">All</dd>
    <dd><a href="smart-devices-min0-max0-attr287/">BP Monitor</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="smart-devices-min0-max0-attr420/">Electric Kettle</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="smart-devices-min0-max0-attr373/">Fitness Tracker</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="smart-devices-min0-max0-attr311/">Gamepad</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="smart-devices-min0-max0-attr325/">Multi Color LED Bulb</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="smart-devices-min0-max0-attr367/">Smart Home Sensor</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="smart-devices-min0-max0-attr387/">Smart Socket</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="smart-devices-min0-max0-attr347/">TV Box</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="smart-devices-min0-max0-attr281/">Water Tester</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="smart-devices-min0-max0-attr299/">Weight Scale</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="smart-devices-min0-max0-attr336/">Wireless Mouse</a></dd>
</dl>
```

What I want to do is change the height based on numbers of filters and i have this code for it

```
$(".filter-list").each(function(index, element) {
    var childnum=$(this).find("dd").length;
    var row=Math.ceil(childnum/6);
    if(row>1){
        $(this).parent().find(".more").show();
        $(this).find(".children").addClass("filter-list-row"+row);  
    }
});
```

This code should change this

```
<dl class="filter-list clearfix filter-list-row-2">
```

to

```
<dl class="filter-list clearfix filter-list-row-3">
```

But its not changing this please help me how can i make it work

Comment: There is nothing in your sample to match `..filter-list`, and it seems your code assumes it will match something that is an ancestor of the sample. Please enough to re-create.

Comment: I have edited the main code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> $(this).find(".children")
> ```

As `$(this)` is the element being worked on (ie. `$(".filter-list")`) you are updating a child with class `children`. There is no such element.

To update the current element (which is what you want) just use

```
$(this).addClass("filter-list-row"+row);
```